# Knapsack with double data types

Tags: c++, algorithm

For all the Knapsack problem that I've seen so far on the internet, all of them have the form (cost, value) given a capacity of the cost variable. All of the problems seems to have cost as an integer only which makes it quite convenient to make a 2D array for Value and Keep array. But what if the cost variable isn't an integer but instead a double data type? There's no way to make a Value and Keep array based on the double data type. How can I approach this situation?

Ex:

budget: $3458

item_name(laptop)    cost(1177.44)  value (131)

item_name(desktop)   cost(1054.44) value(35)

item_name(GPU)     cost(1252.66) value(105)

item_name(CPU)     cost(946.021) value(136)

Comment: Why can't you store integers in `double`s?

Comment: The point isn't that double can't hold integers because they can. The main point is that the method for solving Knapsach problem requires 2 2D array, namely Value and Keep. But the column an integer of cost. But in this case, the cost is a double, which is not possible to construct the 2D array

Comment: But an array of `struct { double cost; int value }` or some container of  `std::pair<double,cost>` or ....

Comment: I think the method for solving this problem is different from what you guys have in mind. Please refer to the following video for the method that I'm referring to: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fDAOvgK11s&nohtml5=False

Comment: `(CPU) cost(946.021)` is that (10^-3) the maximum precision used?

Comment: yes, Max precision is 3

Comment: Then multiply the cost by 1000 and you have intergers.

Comment: In the situation when 3 precision is used, what if the precision isn't defined at the beginning?

Comment: Most of the time folks use integers to represent money because `double`s don't always equal what you think they should. Hard to make a good comparison between A and B when A might be 4.99999999999 and B could be 5.00000001.

Comment: So in a situation when cost is a double and precision isn't defined, how can one solve this knapsack problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can scan your input for the smallest exponent (using `frexp()`), and add in the mantissa precision (53 bits?) to find a scaling factor that will convert all your numbers to exactly proportionate integers.

You will need a bigint library to handle the resulting integers, though.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a dynamic program that finds the least costly solution for each value, with 2D arrays for Cost and Keep instead of Value and Keep. (The difference between the programs is minor.)